# Converting Decimal to Hex is truncating the first digit

Tags: c, string, char, int, hex

I have a function to convert decimal to HEX but it's truncating the first character when returning the hex string. Why and how is it truncating the returned string?

this is the char string I'm dissecting:

```
str = "095154.000,4506.1389N,07389.6017W,2.00,290.0,3,299.12,0.08,0.04,120417,05";
```

Code:

```
char str[90];
char** tokens;
tokens = str_split(str, ',');

strncpy(tempTime, *(tokens)+9, 6);tempTime[7]="\0";

num = atoi(tempTime);
char hex_response[(sizeof(long int) * CHAR_BIT / 4) + 1];
printf("%s", int_hex(num, hex_response));

char* int_hex(long int num, char* hextresponse)
{
    sprintf(hex_response, "%lX", (unsigned long)num);

    return hextresponse;
}
```

hex_response returns 73B2 and it should return 173B2

Comment: `char tempTime = "082431";` won't compile. Please create [mcve].

Comment: `hex_response` in the calling code has wrong type; you should really post accurate code that compiles - i.e. the question should include the code you are asking about, rather than code that bares a passing similarity - otherwise we will be addressing the wrong problem.

Comment: The function `dec_hex` is misleadingly named since it is not converting "decimal to hex", but rather an integer to a hex string representation; you already performed the decimal string reprsentation to integer conversion with `atoi()`

Comment: It is also not a good idea to pass a variable string as the format string argument to `printf()`; use instead the format string "%s", and pass the string to be output as a second argument.

Comment: Making the buffer length for the hex the same as the length of the decimal is safe (because it will always be as long to longer) but makes little sense.  Hex representation requires exactly one character for each four bits, so the buffer can more appropriately be sized for the length of a `long int`.

Comment: It is not clear what `tempTime` is or contains, but presumably points to `"095154.000..."` given the expected value?  You should ideally post complete code that reproduces the problem - these are still broken fragments.

Comment: This is still not "real" code; `int_hex()` takes an argument named `hextresponse`, but writes to `hex_response`.  Write the code, compile it, and copy & paste code that at least compiles!

Comment: Array elements are indexed from from zero, and charavter constants use single quotes, so should be `tempTime[6 ]= '\0' ;`.  Your inability to post plausible/compilable code is severely hampering giving an accurate answer.  There is no point in addressing this question when this is certainly not the actual code producing the error - we'll just end up addressing the flaws in your post rather than the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change the following code

```
num = atoi(tempTime);  // String to int conversion
```

to

```
num = atol(tempTime);  // String to long conversion
```

Comment: While it is certainly correct in this case to use `atol()`; what platform are you using where `int` and `long int` are not the same size?  Or are you using some antique 16 bit compiler? That would have been useful information.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Atmel Studio 6.

Comment: I meant the _target_ platform, not the _development_ platform.  Moreover Atmel Studio can be used for developing for Atmel's ARM and AVR, so the answer is not enlightening, but given that this is the solution, you are presumably targeting AVR?  My point is that had you stated that in the question or tagged it, the error may have been spotted more quickly.  Credit for posting an answer however rather then just "disappearing".

Comment: It is an AVR platform. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Clifford, Just have one question for you so I understand better. Can you explain the "(sizeof(long int) * CHAR_BIT / 4) + 1" part of the code? Thank you

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` is defined in limits.h and is the number of bits in a `char` (typically but not universally 8); `sizeof(long int)` is the size in `char`s of a `long int`, `4` is the number of bits which a hex digit _exactly_ represents (0x0 to 0xF).  So the expression calculates the number of characters needed to represent then maximum length hex string possible from a `long int`.  Say a `long int` is 4 bytes (32 bit), then the expression yields (4 * 8) / 4 = 8 - the number of characters needed to represent a 32 bit value in hex.